# IsAwake always YES albeit SetSleepingAllowed

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, fixture

got a CClayer with many b2bodies and fixtures etc.

all b2_body objects are allowsleeping set to true. but they never sleeps.

notes:
all b2_body ‘s :setAwake are TRUE at initial creation.
all b2_body ‘s :setActive are TRUE at initial creation.
all fixture.friction is 0.001 or 0. no difference

got a custom simple Contact Listener class...

when I check the velocity via
b2Vec2 velocity = b->GetLinearVelocity();
velocity.Length();

is zero. but somehow b->IsAwake() is always YES.

it seems some of bodies are jiggling back and forth infititely with a very little bit velocities.
yes they are stacked.

what may be the reason ?or is there a method to fix this problemma ?

should I stop linear velocities of contact bodies in my custom contactClass ?or...

thank you.

Comment: are these bodies stacked? If so, "noise" in the simulation may prevent bodies from falling asleep because they keep pushing each other ever so slightly.

Comment: or is there a parameter for velocity damping for box2d bodies that I missed?

Comment: checking velocity.all body velocity Lengths are like 0.0000001234 (float32).
is there a way to remove noise or forcing small velovities to zero ?
or should I set restituion of bodies to something different than 0 ?
or a better method to prevent this problem ?

Comment: it seems I commented all lines of PreSolve method in my custom contactlistener. is there be the source of problem ?

Comment: really the problem is that two bodies in contact will wake each other up, so even the slightest jitter can be an issue with gravity always pulling the bodies down. You could manually set them to sleep though.